# Deploying V3 OpenShift Git projects

Tags: openshift

I have been using V2 OpenShift and to deploy for example:
https://github.com/vpapakir/uptime-openshift

using V2 was very simple. Just select the project and click create.

With V3 I am not sure how to proceed, so I first created a Node.js and Mongo 
environment. That works fine.

But now I want to add the:
https://github.com/vpapakir/uptime-openshift

To this node, mongo environment but not sure how to do it?

Or is still possible to simply add the Git project above, without having to create a node, mongo container first?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the deploy is completely different. V2 use cartridges and V3 docker.

For a mongo container you can use this template https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/master/examples/db-templates/mongodb-persistent-template.json

I recommend for node.js the s2i template from here https://github.com/openshift-s2i/s2i-nodejs-community#usage

This isn't a finished solution, like the git repository. For example, you have to pass the database variables to the node.js application via environment variables.

And I found this complete example: https://github.com/openshift/nodejs-ex